# Why is the servlet request parameter incorrect?

Tags: html, servlets, parameters

I'm obviously not correctly understanding servlet parameter access.
Hope someone can help.

Scenario to produce issue for attached sample code:

1. initially invoking the servlet executes doGet() and 'action' is null
2. clicking the 'Calculate' button executes doPost) and 'action' is 'Calculate'
3. clicking the 'Open' href executes the doGet() and 'action' is 'Open'
4. clicking the 'Calculate' button executes doPost() and 'action' is 'Open'

   Why is the 'action' not 'Calculate' as it was in #2?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ProblemServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/problem")
public class ProblemServlet extends HttpServlet {
    String statusMessage = "";
    
    //private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * 
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String action = "";
        try {
            //action should be 'null' or 'Open'
            action = (req.getParameter("action") + "").trim();
            req.setAttribute("action", action);
            statusMessage = "doGet() 'action' parameter = '" + action + "'";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            statusMessage = "doGet() 'action' parameter = null";
        }
        
        produceHtmlPage(res, statusMessage);
    }

    /**
     *  
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String action = "";
        try {
            //action should be 'Calculate', but is 'Open'
            action = (req.getParameter("action") + "").trim();
            req.setAttribute("action", action);
            statusMessage = "doPost() 'action' parameter = '" + action + "'";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            statusMessage = "doPost() 'action' parameter = null";
        }
        
        produceHtmlPage(res, statusMessage);
    }

    private void produceHtmlPage(HttpServletResponse res, String statusMessage) throws IOException {
        ServletOutputStream out = res.getOutputStream();
        res.setContentType("text/html");

        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println(" <a href='http://localhost:8080/RetireProject/problem?action=Open'>Open</a>");
        out.println("<br> <br>");
        out.println(" <form name=aForm method=post bgcolor=#dddddd>");
        out.println("  <input type=button name=action value=Calculate onClick='submit();'>");
        // is this hidden input action requred??
        out.println("  <input type=hidden name=action value=Calculate>");
        out.println(" </from>");
        out.println("<br> <br>");
        out.println(statusMessage);
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");

        out.close();
        return;
    }
}
```